# how long will it take to overflow a long by mere increment (starting from zero)?

Tags: java

If I have code like this

```
    for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++)
    {
        //do something trivial
    }
```

How long will it take theoretically for the loop to finish?

Comment: The title of the question does not align with the actual question posed. Please edit one or the other. Are you interested in modulo arithmetic or execution speed?

Comment: done. the new title reflects the post much better IMHO

Comment: oh, about 68 years, for sufficiently short longs and mid-sized "something trivials" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: I thought JIT would remove the loop if "something trivial" could be calculated without it. It didn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Suppose, just for argument's sake, that you've got a very fast computer that can perform about 2 billion loop iterations per second (a 2 GHz machine could just *barely* do that if there really isn't anything in the loop). Since `Long.MAX_VALUE` is 2 billion times 4 billion, that loop will take around 4 billion seconds, or something over 120 years.

There's no point in starting that loop today. Wait until computers get faster, and then it will be done sooner.

Comment: I think longs are half that--I'm not sure I've got my decimals right, but longs are signed so it's 2^63/4bil=2.3bil.

Comment: The math already accounts for that.  Hence the "2 billion times 4 billion" (2^31 * 2^32).

Comment: How did you calculate "2 GHz machine can perform about 2 billion loop iterations per second"?

Comment: @Dennis 2 GHz = 2 billion clock ticks per second. So if you'd have a processor which could do 1 "loop operation" per clock tick (which is overly optimistic), that's what you'd get. It's just a ballpark figure for the example, not an exact value.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer you are looking for is: It will not finish in your lifetime.

Edit:  I should qualify that--On existing hardware or any hardware I can conceive of; perhaps when quantum computing becomes popular you will have to re-evaluate this question.

Comment: I don't see any valid reason to downvote this. So adding +1 to compensate.

Comment: i don't think this is correct.  If computers continue on the trend they have been on, this will easily be doable in a lifetime. Every time a computer doubles in speed it cuts the time in half, which means one doubling of speed will make it 60 years.  Also, loop iteration is not in the class of problems quantum computers will be able to solve using their black magic.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - It is implicit that the OP is asking about starting the computation "now" using a computer he can obtain "now", and letting the computation run uninterrupted until it is finished. Otherwise, the question has no sensible answer.

Comment: @stephen, i think it is a general question; nothing is implied.  OP did not mention the hardware, so I think it is peferctly legit to theorize on modern hardware, then talk about trends.  regardless, quantum computers wouldn't help in loop iteration.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - so what is the answer then?  How many years on your hypothetical computer?  And why does this make @Bill K's answer incorrect?

Comment: @stephen, because quantum computers wont help -- that part of his answer is incorrect.  

And while no hardware nowadays will complete the loop (maybe if we built a specialized loop processor), in our lifetimes we might see some that would complete, because each doubling of speed cuts computation time in half.  Think about it.  The first "modern" computers, were in the sixties.  Half a lifetime later, our computers are *billions* of time faster....

Gets interesting when you think about the move to 128 bit computing. ;)

Comment: @hvgotcodes - ok, the quantum computing stuff is irrelevant.  But we've already gotten to a point where Moore's law is broken.  And random hypothesizing about how processor speeds *might* change over our lifetimes does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @stephen, the OP wasn't practical.  "How long will it take theoretically for the loop to finish?"  The right answer is "theoretically, it depends how many loops you can process a second."

its not a practical question.  computer science is about solving problems no matter how large the problem space is. If the answer depends on brute force (like loop processing), the problem isn't solvable.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - if you interpret theoretical in that sense, then the answer has to be "However long it takes to do `2**64` register to register 64 bit additions."  And I'm damn sure the OP wasn't after that as an answer.

Comment: @steven i interpreted it to mean "how long to do 2^63-1 trivial operations, one after the other". if you count a trivial op as flipping a bit, from my answer below, the answer is 7 months with the fastest bit flipping machine people have built.

Comment: I just threw in the quantum computer stuff as a bit of a joke--I'm kind of taking a class in them now and bogged down in imaginary numbers and matrices... However I'm fairly sure they could, in fact, speed up the counting significantly (For instance, most iterative operations are done in a single operation in QC, it just executes every single state at once.)

Answer (score 2):

This might take a life time to run.

But according to the title of the question, I guess you are trying to run a loop for very high number of times and you are planning to break the loop when a certain condition occurs. i.e. You have some

```
if (ancondition == true)
{ 
   break; 
}
```

And you just need to make sure you are not getting any exception due to overflows. (ex: you are going to monitor a seismic sensor for years.) So in that scope you are safe to go.

But in the other hand this is not a good programming approach. Definitely you can improve the code by using another way.(May be periodical checks)

Answer (score 1):

put this into wolframalpha.com

(2^63 -1)/(2*10^9) seconds

the 2^63-1 is the current value of MAX_VALUE, and 2*10^9 is a 2 GHZ processor that increments the loop once every clock tick.

now put

(2^63 -1)/(4*10^9) seconds

that represents a doubling of machine speed to 4 GHZ.

the fastest supercomputer does 1.75 petaflops (10^15).  Thats a parallelized application, so its not one big loop, but if you ask "how long would it take to do 2^63-1 flops", on that machine its

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2^63+-1)/(1.75*10^15)+seconds

The fastest speed we have gotten a transistor to run at is 500 GHZ.  from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore's_law

"the transistor operated above 500 GHz at 4.5 K (−451 °F/−268.65 °C)[41] and simulations showed that it could likely run at 1 THz (1,000 GHz). However, this trial only tested a single transistor."

so if you plug that into wolfram alpha, you get 7 months.  So a single transistor is not a loop processing unit, but you get the point.  Conceivable hardware is within our technological grasp, even to churn through 2^63-1 loop iterations. If you consider the OP to be "how long to do 2^63 bit flips", then this machine meets that criteria, and easily completes in a lifetime.

But when we move to 128 bit computing, we have no chance...

Comment: I wouldn't expect 128-bit computing any time soon. It may seem cliche to say "64 bits ought to be big enough for everybody", but for the most part it is. How often do you have to store numbers larger than 2^63?

Answer (score 1):

one possible answer is zero second. the compiler could be very aggressive and optimize off your entire loop, since it apparently doesn't do anything interesting...

here's a great related story: compilers optimized off a loop which searches for Fermat's Last Theorem's counter example. because the Theorem is correct (so we are told) and there is no counter example, the loop should never terminate. but compilers decide it should terminate.

http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161

(the article mentions that a java compiler is not allowed to terminate the fermat loop)

Comment: Switching to ints, on 5u20 I got `0.409u 0.133s 0:00.59 89.8%     0+0k 0+4io 2pf+0w` (I think that means about half a second.)